# C Why can't a void pointer store a float value?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to return a float value but when I print it out, I get 0.0.

```
float floating = 4.5;

void* function(){
    void* test = &floating;
    return test;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
     printf("%f\n", test());
     return 0;
}
```

Any ideas on why it's not printing out 4.5?  Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm still fairly new to this.

Comment: You need to explicitly cast that to float* when reading or c will not know how many bytes to read from that pointer.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? although this is of course not a *great* question, OP actually tried something, probably having read about `void *` being a generic pointer. Understanding all the implications takes some time and I think it's worth explaining ...

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your `function()` is *actually spelled* as `test()`, `%f` expects a `float` value. You're supplying a `void *`. It's wrong and [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: `void` being an incomplete type, you cannot dereference a `void` pointer directly. You need to cast the pointer to the required type before dereferencing. For example,

```
printf("%f\n", *( (float *) test() ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
printf("%f\n", *( (float*)function() ));
```

Answer (score 5):

Trying to provide a bit more details about that:

First, from how you phrased your question, you should understand that pointers don't store values, they store addresses of objects. `void` is no type at all, and a `void *` pointer might store the address of *anything* (as long as it's data, but I don't want to overcomplicate my answer right here).

That's probably where you came from in the first place. But then you made two mistakes:

1. The `%f` format specifier of `printf()` doesn't expect a pointer, it expects a value. There's one operation called *dereferencing* a pointer that fetches the value the pointer points to. In [c](/questions/tagged/c) expressions, you have the *dereferencing operator* written as an asterisk (`*`) in front of your value to do that.
2. So how can you read a value without knowing the type? You can't! That's why dereferencing a `void *` pointer is illegal. Means, even if you didn't forget the asterisk and wrote for example `printf("%f\n", *(test()));`, the code would be wrong (and this time, your compiler would catch the error).

That being said, `void *` pointers in [c](/questions/tagged/c) are meant as a *generic* pointer and are therefore implicitly convertible to and from any other data pointer type (note this is different in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)). So one way to write your program correctly would be:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
     float *f = test();
     printf("%f\n", *f);
     return 0;
}
```

**edit:** From the fact that `void *` is implicitly convertible to/from other data pointer types follows your `test()` could be as simple as that:

```
void *test()
{
     return &floating;
}
```

**edit2:** As you're new to pointers, adding an advice not directly related to your question: In a variable declaration in [c](/questions/tagged/c), the asterisk *binds* to the *identifier* (variable name), not to the type. This means you read `int * foo;` not as "foo is a variable of type *pointer to int*" but as "foo is a pointer variable of type *int*". This has a serious implication when writing e.g. `int * foo, bar;` -- foo will be a pointer, bar a normal variable. Therefore the advice is: make it explicit by writing e.g. `void *test` instead of `void* test`.

Comment: Hmm, not convinced: [foo as pointer to int](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*+foo)

Comment: Apart from being ambiguous (it doesn't tell you exactly whether being a pointer is part of the type or a property of the variable) -- what exactly makes you trust this site? Try `int * foo, bar;` -> *syntax error*. Great.

Comment: And .. if you want it *completely* correct, you'd have to cite the standard text, IMHO not that helpful for a newbie, but then you'd get that being a pointer is called a *type derivator* and it's part of the [declarator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.5) (as opposed to the *type specifier*). Of course you can *define* your own type including such a derivator, then you will have a *pointer type* (`typedef int *pint`), but that's often considered *bad pactice* because it breaks with the natural assumption that the `*` is always visible in the *declarator* of any pointer...

Answer (score 4):

What printf sees is a parameter value. That value isn't a float, but is a pointer to a float.  You would need to cast it back to a float* and dereference it.

Answer (score 2):

I have test in my IDE. The `function()` is correct, what you need to modify is `printf()`. My answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
float floating = 4.5;

void* test(){
    void* test = &floating;
    return test;
}

int main()
{

    printf("%f\n", *(float *)test());  //modify here
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The `%f` conversion specifier expects it's corresponding argument to have type `float`; you're passing it a `void *`, hence the garbage output.

Change that to

```
printf( "%f\n", * ((float *) test()) );
```

You have to convert the `void *` returned from `test` to a `float *`, then dereference the result to get the actual `float` value.  The cast is necessary, since you cannot directly deference a `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont print 4.5, because you are returning a pointer over the variable "floating" not the variable itself.

You have to change your code to :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
     printf("%f\n", (*(float*)function()));
     return 0;
}
```